# Starting a created flow on a selected document

Tags: document, flow

I can't seem to figure out how to start a flow that I have created for a selected document. I don't want to hardcode a list or document library into the flow - but rather give users the option to select the document and trigger the flow.

A typical scenario is when users want to trigger a multi-level approval on a selected document.

Secondly, I'd like this flow to appear in the right-click menu, on the selected item, similar to Request Sign-off. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://india.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/31a5422e6d8b4c0d9fdb95f298130e4d/complete-a-custom-action-for-the-selected-file/) template and add/remove your own actions. It has a trigger "For a Selected File". To run the flow, you need to select the file and click on ellipsis (3 dots) and then hover on "Flow" and there you will find the flow attached to the library just like Request Sign-off.

Hope it helps. Please mark it as answer if this solves your query.

Comment: Thank you. That works!!